# lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system

Tags: shell, fstab, lsof, tmpfs

when I use `lsof` as regular user, I get following warnings:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tmpfs file system /home/testuser/.cache
```

`testuser` is another user on my systems, and my own user has no access to the `tmpfs` filesystem mounted at `/home/testuser/.cache`.

I suspect, lsof found in `/etc/fstab` (or in `/proc/mounts`) that this `tmpfs` exists and tries to search it and fails on not having permissions to other user's home:

```
$ grep /home/testuser/.cache /proc/mounts
tmpfs /home/testuser/.cache tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,size=4194304k,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
```

Anyways, how can I supress these warnings, or tell `lsof` not to search paths of other users, or something that would get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable warnings with `-w`:

```
lsof -w
```